# Execution sequence of Touch, Scroll and Intersection observer callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, touch, intersection-observer

This question is regarding the sequence of execution of touch, scroll and intersection observer callback.

I have a simple mobile web app which has a scrollable list view where each item is 100px in height and I have intersection Observer put on viewport but with a top margin of -100px(`rootMargin: "-100px 0px 0px 0px"`).

It is done in this manner so that my list-item can be observed as soon as it scrolls up.

Intersection observer is like this:

```
const io = new IntersectionObserver(viewportBottomObserverCallback, {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: "-100px 0px 0px 0px",
  threshold: [0, 1]
})
```

I have touchmove handler, scroll handler and intersection observer callback.

Now as soon as I touch and swipe up, I am seeing a consistent behavior in execution of these handlers/callbacks. First `onTouchMove` is called, then `onScroll` is called and at last `viewportBottomObserverCallback` is called. Is this always like that? This question is important because if I know that these DOM events are always called in this sequence then my code will become very deterministic. Generally this is not the case with any other DOM events.

To visualize it more better I am attaching screenshot of my chrome's profiler. The portion inside blue is my intersection observer callback.

[image]

### EDIT:

I am testing this on chrome in responsive mode with device being iPhone 6/7/8.

One more question: Does the calculation and queuing of tasks(intersection observer) to event loop happens only after `update layer tree` is done, specifically this task - https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/#calculate-intersection-rect-algo ?

Answer (score 2):

To sum up -

**All microtasks are completed before any other event handling, rendering or any other macrotask takes place. This guarantees that the application is basically the same (no mouse coordinate changes, no new network data, etc) between microtasks.**

So yep!  It is deterministic.

Stepping back, the browser uses the event loop to switch between scripting, rendering, painting, networking, eventing.  During each turn of the event loop, one Macrotask is executed.  Macrotasks are actions such as UI events (mousemove), DOM manipulation and setTimeout. Microtasks are run after the Macrotask is dequeued. So things like **IntersectionObserver** and **Promise.resolve** happen in the Microtask queue before rendering and painting.

https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/#event-loop

https://javascript.info/event-loop

Comment: Could you please point out a place where the standards says that the Intersection Observer uses the microtasks? I cannot find it. [This](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/#queue-intersection-observer-task) operates with just the tasks only.